# MDI MdiWindowListItem OnClick

Tags: c#, mdiparent

I have a basic MDI form, with "Window" as a menu option that was generated by default.  I can open child windows and under Window it shows up as expected.   My problem is, my child windows are different heights and widths.  When I open the child windows originally, I can resize the MDIParent to the width and height of the child.

My problem exists when someone clicks on the child menu under the "Window" menu.   I'm trying to figure out how to capture that, so I can resize the MDIParent the size of my child windows, since that isn't controled by me.

I've looked around for MdiWindowListItem and OnClick with no luck.  I'm assuming I can do an override, but not sure what to override.   Anyone ever done this?

Comment: Use the MdiChildActivate event.  Very little point in using MDI when you do these kind of things btw.

Comment: Reason being, each child is basically it's own application. Scripting project I have. Each form is a completely different script process and I didn't want to create 15 applications, when I can do it this way and share some of the resources. Some of them have 4 prompts when some may have 30. Don't like the form looking blank when there are only 4. This is a dev tool only.   That will work, posted it as an answer, I'll give you credit.  Thanks.